# remove white spaces from a target csv under a specific column

Tags: csv, vbscript, wsh

I want to remove white spaces from a csv file ideally from a particular column leaving only the single space instead of additional unwanted spaces. I have the following script that can achieve this but need help in implementing the following script to check a target csv under a particular column and remove the whitespaces.

here is the script:

```
'Start by trimming leading/trailing spaces
str = Trim(str)

'Now, while we have 2 consecutive spaces, replace them
'with a single space...
Do While InStr(1, str, "  ")
str = Replace(str, "  ", " ")
Loop
```

Ideally i would like to call the script like this:

```
Cscript whitespaceremover.vbs target.csv 'column_name'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think my example below can be polished, but I hope it's good enough to get started.

My demo CSV file "target.csv":

```
column_name1,column_name2,column_name3
abc 123, dfr 1145  wse, ht6
axv 358, dgt 2245  ekl, x7r
amn 772, fxw 7633  foo, pmn
```

An example "whitespaceremover.vbs":

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim fso, file, column
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With WScript.Arguments
    If .Count <> 2 Then
        WScript.Echo "Error: Needs to arguments."
        WScript.Quit(-1)
    End If
    file   = .Item(0)
    column = .Item(1)
End With
If Not fso.FileExists(file) Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: File " & UCase(file) & " not found."
    WScript.Quit(-2)
End If
Dim csvFile, csvHeader, iColumn, idx
Set csvFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file, ForReading)
If Not csvFile.AtEndOfStream Then
    csvHeader = Split(csvFile.ReadLine, ",", -1, 1)
Else
    WScript.Echo "Error: File " & UCase(file) & " is empty."
    csvFile.Close
    WScript.Quit(-3)
End If
iColumn = -1
For idx = 0 To UBound(csvHeader)
    If csvHeader(idx) = column Then
        iColumn = idx
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If iColumn < 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: column " & UCase(column) & " not found."
    csvFile.Close
    WScript.Quit(-4)
End If
Dim csvFile2, arLine, strLine
Set csvFile2 = fso.OpenTextFile(file & ".csv", ForWriting, True)
csvFile2.WriteLine Join(csvHeader, ",")
Do Until csvFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = Trim(csvFile.ReadLine)
    arLine  = Split(strLine, ",", -1, 1)
    Do While InStr(1, arLine(iColumn), "  ")
        arLine(iColumn) = Replace(arLine(iColumn), "  ", " ")
    Loop
    strLine = Join(arLine, ",")
    csvFile2.WriteLine strLine
Loop
csvFile.Close
csvFile2.Close
Set csvFile  = Nothing
Set csvFile2 = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Result (new file "target.csv.csv"):

```
column_name1,column_name2,column_name3
abc 123, dfr 1145 wse, ht6
axv 358, dgt 2245 ekl, x7r
amn 772, fxw 7633 foo, pmn
```

P.S. Some note I forgot to post. For test simplicity I put double space in the second column. Shortly, to see the script in action use `column_name2` as command-line argument, i.e.:

```
Cscript whitespaceremover.vbs target.csv column_name2
```

**Edit**

After reading Ansgar Wiechers comment about `Replace` function I finally decide to make some tests. Maybe the above code is slow compared to regular expression, but it`s working. Here is my proof example:

```
str1 = "1" & Space(2) & "2" & Space(4) & "3" _
    & Space(1) & "4" & Space(6) & "5"
WScript.Echo "Original string: ", str1
Do While InStr(1, str1, "  ")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "  ", " ")
Loop
WScript.Echo "New string: ", str1
'Result>>
'Original string:  1  2    3 4      5
'New string:  1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that `Replace(str, "  ", " ")` won't produce the desired result when there are 3 or more consecutive spaces. Replacing with a regular expression (`" +"`) is probably a more robust approach.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - You're right, I'm just not so good with regular expression. If you like you may provide the OP with your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to the answer [Panayot Karabakalov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014190/1630171) provided: simply replacing two spaces with a single one may yield undesired results when there are sequences of 3 or more consecutive spaces. A line like this:

```
foo   bar      baz
```

would be replaced to this:

```
foo  bar   baz
```

*not* to this:

```
foo bar baz
```

The reason is that `Replace` continues *after* a replaced string. For instance, running `Replace("aaaa", "aa", "a")` will first replace the first 2 `a` characters:

`aaaa` → `aaa`

then replace the next 2 `a` characters *after* the replacement string:

`aaa` → `aa`

and then terminate.

A more robust solution for collapsing spaces (or character sequences in general) is replacement by regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = " +"  '<-- means "a sequence of one or more spaces"
re.Global = True

text = "foo   bar      baz"

WScript.Echo re.Replace(text, " ")
```

Output:

```
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Your comment about `Replace` function bring my attention, as I have the filing that I miss something, so I made some test, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't face all guidelines, but maybe it will be helpful for someone.

```
' USAGE: CScript WhiteSpaceRemover.vbs Target_File.csv Column_Number

Set oArgs = WScript.Arguments
If oArgs.Count = 2 Then
    strInputFileName = oArgs(0)
    intColumn = oArgs(1) - 1
    strOutputFileName = PrepareOutputPath(strInputFileName, "_new")

    WriteTextFile strOutputFileName, TrimCsv(ReadTextFile(strInputFileName), intColumn)

End If
Set oArgs = Nothing

Function TrimCsv (strFileContent, intColumn)
    ' usuwa niepotrzebne spacje w polach tabeli CSV
    strFileContent = Replace(strFileContent, vbCrLf, vbLf)
    arrFileContent = Split(strFileContent, vbLf)
    strFileContent = ""
    For Each strLine in arrFileContent
        If Not Len(strLine) = 0 Then
            arrRecord = Split(strLine, ";")

'           for specified column number
            arrRecord(intColumn) = Trim(arrRecord(intColumn))

'           for all columns
'           For iCount = LBound(arrRecord) To UBound(arrRecord)
'               arrRecord(iCount) = Trim(arrRecord(iCount))
'           Next

            AddToList strFileContent, Join(arrRecord, ";"), vbCrLf
            Erase arrRecord
        End If
    Next
    TrimCsv = strFileContent
    Erase arrFileContent
End Function


Function PrepareOutputPath(strFileName, strSuffix)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With objFSO
        strPath = .GetParentFolderName(strFileName)
        strName = .GetBaseName(strFileName)
        strExt = .GetExtensionName(strFileName)
    End With
    PrepareOutputPath = AddToList(strPath, strName & strSuffix, "\")
    PrepareOutputPath = AddToList(PrepareOutputPath, strExt, ".")
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function


Function AddToList(strList, strValue, strDelim)
    ' add delimiter between values
    If strList = "" Then
        AddToList = strValue
    Else
        AddToList = strList & strDelim & strValue
    End If
    strList = AddToList
End Function 


Function ReadTextFile(strFileName)
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"

    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile(strFileName)
    ReadTextFile = objStream.ReadText()
    objStream.Close

    Set objStream = Nothing
End Function


Sub WriteTextFile (strFileName, strFileContent)
    adSaveCreateNotExist = 1
    adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    adWriteChar = 0
    adWriteLine = 1

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"

    objStream.Open
    objStream.WriteText strFileContent, adWriteChar
    objStream.SaveToFile strFileName, adSaveCreateOverwrite
    objStream.Close

    Set objStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

best regards

--

Pawel L.