# vbscript files with spaces and tabs

Tags: vbscript

Got a file that I want to separate and put in columns.  Look
like some of the fields in file are separated by spaces and other by tabs.  I want to format so the the name and address and etc are separated in columns.

```
enter code here
strStarter = "RT 29 MONTPELIER VA 23100     23100"

intStarter = Len(strStarter)
For i = intStarter to 2 Step -1
strChars = Space(i)
strStarter = Replace(strStarter, strChars, " ")
 strStarter1 = Replace(strStarter, vbTab,  " " )
Next

arrStarter = Split(strStarter, " ")
arrStarter2= Split(strStarter1,vbTab)

 For Each strUnit in arrStarter
    Wscript.Echo strUnit
Next
```

Comment: By which distinguishing feature do you separate the columns? Each word in its own column? Do you want the result to be formatted text, or are you going to process it further? Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/17819043/69820

Answer (score 0):

I **think** that you have a tab-delimited file, perhaps with sequences of blanks in some fields. In that case you should

1. Split on vbTab to get the fields
2. normalize blanks in all/some of the fields

To normalize spaces you can use Trim() for leading/trailing blanks and a RegExp.Replace with "+" or " +" as pattern and " " as replacement.

(have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17029743/603855))

Answer (score 0):

I made you a Ruby-like split function to split a string based on a Regular Expression pattern

```
'the following string contains a tab
strStarter = "RT 29 MONTPELIER BEFORETAB    AFTERTAB VA 23100     23100"

Function rsplit(string, pattern)
    Dim r
    Set r = New RegExp
    r.Global = True
    r.Pattern = "[^"&pattern&"]+"
    Set rsplit = r.Execute(string)
End Function

For each unit in rsplit(strStarter, " |\t") 
  wscript.echo unit
Next
```

Gives

```
RT
29
MONTPELIER
BEFORETAB
AFTERTAB
VA
23100
23100
```