# split text file VBS and give column headers

Tags: vbscript

1. Parse the name field as "Last Name", First Name, Middle. If there is a second name then the second name needs to be in its own field. Not all names have a second name.
2. If the name is a business I would need the entire name in the last name field and a blank in the first and middle names.

My code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
x=0

on error resume next 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Test.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    arrName = Split(strLine, vbTab)
    msgbox(arrName(x))
    x = x+1    
Loop
```

**file looks as follows**

```
Name    2nd name
ABDELMAGID  A SMITH & LISA S    
ABDELMAGID  A SMITH & LISA S    
CLEVELAND  SANDY LEE    
CLEVELAND  SANDY LEE    
WHALEN  STEPHEN H & JOAN L  
WHALEN  STEPHEN H & JOAN L  
BANK TWO OF VIRGINIA INC    C/O DOE JOHN
BANK TWO OF VIRGINIA INC    C/O DOE JOHN
BANK TWO OF VIRGINIA INC    C/O DOE JOHN
SMITH JOHN ELLIS JR 
JONES JOHN III
```

Comment: the sample is usless without the vbTabs marked; the use of x in the line loop is wrong; the global OERN is stupid.

Comment: The example would be more helpful if you showed the expected result. Is an existing "2nd name" field an entirely different name, or is it the first name of the name in the "Name" field? How do you distinguish company names from other names?

Comment: last column should have (ABDELMAGID  ,CLEVELAND, BANK TWO OF VIRGINIA INC) etc ...

Comment: firstname column should have(A,STEPHEN, JOHN ) etc...

Comment: middle name column should(SMITH, LEE, ELLIS) etc .....

Comment: last colum called C/o should have (Lisa A, John Doe) etc .....

Comment: That won't work. You have some space-separated words (`BANK TWO OF VIRGINIA INC`) that are supposed to be treated as a single term, and other space-separated words (e.g. `SMITH JOHN ELLIS JR`) that are supposed to be treated as separate terms. You need to either fix your input data so that it's better suited for automated processing, or come up with a heuristic to distinguish between these cases.